# look for cells which contain certain value in another sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have two sheets where Sheet 1 has many account names in column C and Sheet 2 has a list of account names in column B.

I would like to search in Sheet 1 column C all cells where the value contains the cell value in Sheet 2 column B and high light them in yellow.

Below are my codes, with with I keep getting error message "Objectiv Variable or With Block variable not set" or "Subsript without range".

```
Sub search_name() ' ' search_name Macro
    Dim a As Range
    Set a = Sheets("NAMES").Range("B1")
    For Each a In Sheets("NAMES").Range("B1:B88")
      Sheets("MASTER").Select
      Columns("C:C").Select
      Selection.Find(a, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      With ActiveCell.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
      End With
    Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

The "Object Variable or With Block variable not set" error occurs if the value in Names sheet is not found in Master sheet.

You need to add error handling to the code

```
Sub search_name() ' ' search_name Macro
    Dim a As Range
    Set a = Sheets("NAMES").Range("B1")
    For Each a In Sheets("NAMES").Range("B1:B3")
      Sheets("MASTER").Select
      Columns("C:C").Select
  On Error GoTo err: 'added this
      Selection.Find(a, After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
        LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
      With ActiveCell.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 65535
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
      End With

  err: ' added this
    Next a
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `conditional formatting` to achieve the same result.

On column `C` in your `MASTER` add the following rule and set a format (e.g. yellow background)

```
=NOT(ISNA(VLOOKUP(C1,Names!$B$1:$B$3,1,FALSE)))
```

This is more helpful if you are adding names to your `NAMES` and / or `MASTER` sheet as you don't need to keep running a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Vasim says to add error handling, but the solution offered just ignores the reason why you are getting the error (next a makes the loop proceed as if nothing had happened) and could lead to later errors if you modify or expand the code.  Better to address the issue, which is that the search as defined may not be finding a value to highlight (this might be unexpected, but you include your column headers in the search, so if they don't match you would not find a value for the first iteration of the search).

So: first you should make sure that the found value is more than nothing.  `.Find` returns a range value, so you can assign the found value to a range variable and use an `If` statement to determine whether the found range exists: `If Not FoundRange is Nothing Then`.

Also, you should generally (but especially when working with two different sheets or two different workbooks) explicitly define your ranges, so if the selected range is not the sheet being worked with, you don't get an error.  Do this by setting `Workbook` and `Worksheet` variables and using them for all `.Range` declarations: `wb.wsA.Range("C:C")`.

Finally, consider working without the `Select` method whenever possible (which is almost always). As users of Excel, we have to select cells before doing anything with them, but VBA does not have that restriction, and it is much faster if your code does NOT select or activate cells before working with them.

I've rewritten your code with all three suggestions incorporated.  Hope this helps with your understanding of what is going on.

```
Sub search_name2() '' search_name Macro

    '~~>dim variables and initial values
        Dim wb As Workbook
            Set wb = ActiveWorkbook
        Dim wsM As Worksheet
            Set wsM = wb.Worksheets("MASTER")
        Dim wsA As Worksheet
            Set wsA = wb.Worksheets("NAMES")
        Dim rngA As Range
            Set rngA = wsA.Range("B1", wsA.Range("B65536").End(xlUp))
        Dim rngCell As Range
        Dim rngFound As Range

    '~~>loop to find matches between worksheet ranges
        For Each rngCell In rngA
          Set rngFound = wsM.Range("C:C").Find(rngCell.Value, After:=wsM.Range("C1"), _
            LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
            MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)
          Application.CutCopyMode = False
          If Not rngFound Is Nothing Then
            With rngFound.Interior
              .Pattern = xlSolid
              .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
              .Color = 65535
              .TintAndShade = 0
              .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
          End If
        Next rngCell

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You should clean up your variable declaration. Try this:

```
Dim ws1 as Worksheet, ws2 as Worksheet
Dim search_range as Range, search_value as Range
Dim acct_name as Range, foundcell as Range, lastcell as Range
Dim firstaddr as String

Set ws1 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("NAMES")
Set ws2 = Thisworkbook.Sheets("MASTER")
Set search_value = ws1.Range("B1:B" & ws1.Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set search_range = ws2.Range("C1:C" & ws2.Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
Set lastcell = search_range.Cells(search_range.Cells.Count)

For Each acct_name In search_value

    Set foundcell = search_range.Find(What:=acct_name, After:=lastcell)

    If Not foundcell Is Nothing Then firstaddr = foundcell.Address

    Do Until foundcell Is Nothing
        With foundcell.Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 65535
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With

        Set foundcell = search_range.FindNext(After:=foundcell)

        If foundcell.Address = firstaddr Then Exit Do
    Loop
Next acct_name
```

Hope this is close to what you need. No way to test it so i leave it to you.

Comment: Several of your variables are declared as `Variant` since they aren't specified (e.g. `ws1`).